# Extracting an object from array of objects using body parser

Tags: javascript, express, body-parser

I am sending an array of objects to a post route in an express app.

my form (in an ejs format) is:

```
<form action="/archiveList/<%= list._id %>" method="POST">`
<input type="hidden" name="list" value = <%= items %> >
</form>
```

My post route is:

```
router.post("/archiveList/:id", function (req,res){
var array = req.body.list;
array.forEach(function(obj){
console.log(obj.name)
res.redirect("/main");
});
```

This gives me a error that "array.forEach is not a function"
If I:

```
console.log(array) // I get "[object"
```

If I

```
console.log(typeof(array)) // I get "string".
```

My app.js includes:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));.
```

If I just send a simple string to the route and extract with req.body, this works fine. Obviously there is something different about sending an array of objects and extracting it with body parser I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please format your question. it's not even readable

Comment: what part needs  formatting? do you want the code?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] showing the problem, including the code sending the data and **exactly** what your client is sending your server (which you can get from your browser's network tools). Please use the various formatting aids in the editor's toolbar to make sure code is marked up as code (the `{}` button), use `pre` if necessary on the data being sent, use backticks to format inline code in the text, etc. It should be possible to post complete server and client MCVE code, as in each case I'd expect it to be less than 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var array = Array.from(req.body.list)
```

If `req.body.list` is an array-like object, this will work.

Comment: This stops the array.forEach is not a function error. But if I try to access the items in the objects they are "undefined"

Comment: Are you also using `app.use(bodyParser.json())`?

Comment: Yes I have that line in app.js along with app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})).

Comment: Just to be clear. Your method is extracting an array but the objects within that array are not being converted to objects (probably just still strings).

Comment: Im sorry, but I'm not familiar with `ejs` syntax, but there is clearly a problem with your array, or the way you are sending it. Did you `console.log` it on the client side to make sure everything is fine?